# Unable to locate file from Terminal - Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, terminal, vmware

I'm trying to install Xcode on Sierra 10.12 running in a VM.

I've downloaded the file (Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip) from the Apple Developers site.

Unable to open it successfully with the archiver, it gets stuck on verifying the digital signature, I attempted a command which I found on the Stack forums that's used to bypass the security and allows me to install downloaded apps from anywhere. This is common practice used to install the Xcode Beta x versions.

However, I'm unable to locate the file using the command from terminal.
After navigating to the Applications folder using:

```
cd Applications/
```

then executing:

```
sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip
```

I'm prompted for my password and then:

```
xattr: No such file: Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip
```

[image: An image of the folder directory & Terminal window]

If anyone can assist, it will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what happens when you try the explicit path to the file, that is:  `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip` ?

Answer (score 3):

You're currently telling Terminal to look in `~/Applications` (the Applications folder within your own home folder). From this screenshot, it appears your `Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip` file is in the `/Applications` folder (within your root folder).

`cd /Applications` *then* running `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine Xcode_8.3_beta_2.xip` should do the trick.

Comment: Haha. Also/or, Xcode could have been installed from the App Store. Also/or, the xip file could be extracted with `xip -x`.